# How do I get code completion for Javascript in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am using VScode to write Javascript.

I have the following code...

```
results = []
results.p
```

When I type the '.p' the 'push' method does not come up in the code completion dropdown dialog. As 'push' is a method on the javascript 'list' I would expect that to be completed.

Is something in my VSCode misconfigured?

Comment: Is the file saved as `.js`? Also make sure the language mode of the document is set to "JavaScript"

Comment: If you add `let results = []` for example you will get completion.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode doesn't know what `results` is, and thus considers it to be

```
declare var results: any
```

To make it to have a type, you should define it yourself, like

```
var results = [] // <- resolves to any[]
let results1 = [] // <- resolves to any[]
const results2 = [] // <- resolves to any[]
```